# TCG\Voyager doesn't get translation on relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, translate, voyager

I use Voyager admin interface (v.1.4) for Laravel (v8.0).
Voyager supports multiple languages (official documentation: https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/v/1.4-1/core-concepts/multilanguage).

I have this relationship:

- Process belongsToMany WorkMachine
- Process hasMany Product

**Process model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;

class Process extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    protected $translatable = ['name', 'meta_description', 'description'];

    public function get_workmachine() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(WorkMachine::class, 'process_workmachine');
    }

    public function get_products() {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'process_product');
    }
```

**WorkMachine model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;

class WorkMachine extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    protected $translatable = ['name', 'meta_description', 'description'];
```

**Product model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;

class Product extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    protected $translatable = ['name'];
```

**In my controller:**

```
$process = App\Models\Process::where('slug', $processSlug)
                    ->with('get_workmachine')
                    ->with('get_products')
                    ->firstOrFail()->translate(app()->getLocale());
```

The problem is: the Process translatable text works, the output language depends from `app()->getLocale()`. But the workmachine texts and products texts aren't translated.

I try also to use:

```
->with(['get_workmachine' => function ($query) { $query->withTranslation('de'); }])
```

But it isn't translated.

Any solutions to translate the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a possible solution!
In my .blade file, instead of:

```
@foreach(json_decode($process->get_workmachine) as $workmachine)
    ...
    ...
@endforeach
```

I added `->translate(app()->getLocale())`:

```
@foreach(json_decode($process->get_workmachine->translate(app()->getLocale())) as $workmachine)
    ...
    ...
@endforeach
```

This works!